# Conceptual misunderstanding of law $\mathbb{P}^{\nu}$ of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

***What I understand :***

Giving Markov transition kernels $(q_t)_{t\ge0}$ and an initial distribution $\nu$ entirely specifies the law of a stochastic process. Indeed If $X^{\nu}$ and $Y^{\nu}$ are two processes such with same transition kernels $(q_t)_{t\ge0}$ and initial distribution $\nu$, in other words $\nu(A)=P(X^{\nu}_0\in A)=P(Y^{\nu}_0\in A)$ then they have the same law, i.e. $\operatorname{law}(X^{\nu})=\operatorname{law}(Y^{\nu})$ which means that for every $A\subset S^T$, we have $$\mathbb{P}\{\omega : (t\mapsto X^{\nu}_t(\omega))\in A\} = \mathbb{P}\{\omega : (t\mapsto Y^{\nu}_t(\omega))\in A\}.$$

Now we can define a probability on $S^T$ by $\mathbb{P}^{\nu}:=\operatorname{law}(X^{\nu})$ and in particular we call $\mathbb{P^{\delta_x}}=:\mathbb{P}^x$.

Then things get weird

***What I don't understand :***

1)

> Rather than considering one Markov process $X^{\nu}$ for every initial
> distribution $\nu$, we may introduce a single canonical process $X$,
> deﬁned as the identity mapping on the path space
> $(S^T,\mathcal{B}(S)^T)$, equipped with the diﬀerent probability
> measures $\mathbb{P}^{\nu}$ .

I am not sure how these two ways of thinking are equivalent.

2. Mostly, I struggle with these kind of phrasing :

> Denote by $\mathbb{P}^x$ the probability measure such that $B = (B_t)_{t≥0}$ is
> a Brownian motion started at $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is $B$ in this case just the process $B:S^T\to S^T, B : \omega\mapsto \omega$ ? But then it wouldn't necessarily be Brownian no?

Or does this mean that we construct a Markov process that is a Brownian motion by specifying for example transition kernels $q_{s,t}(z,A):=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A(z+B_t-B_s)]$ and with initial distribution $\delta_x$ and then we call $\mathbb{P}^x$ the law of this Brownian motion? Wouldn't it make more sense in that case to say "Denote by $\mathbb{P}^x$ the law of $B = (B_t)_{t≥0}$"?

**Addendum**

I think I more or less understand this now. The main calculation that I had difficulty to see is that given $X$ the identity process we have

\begin{align}
P(X^{\nu}\in A)=&P(X\circ X^{\nu}\in A)\\=&P((X\circ X^{\nu})^{-1}(A))\\=&P((X^{\nu})^{-1}\circ X^{-1}(A))\\=&P((X^{\nu})^{-1}(X^{-1}(A)))\\=&P^{\nu}(X^{-1}(A))\\=&P^{\nu}(X\in A)
\end{align}
So say we construct from $(q_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $\nu$ a Markov process/Brownian motion or something. Then the law of the "identity process" $X(\omega)=\omega$ for $\omega\in S^T$ will be the law of the specific Markov process/Brownian motion under the probability $P^{\nu}$.

reference : [Markov process and transition semigroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123885/340973)

Comment: "Wouldn't it make more sense in that case to say..."  What happened to $x$, though?  I'm having trouble finding the "more sense" in this part of the question.  Is there a typo?